# Wine won't install, Does not have valid release file

Tags: software-installation, updates, wine, ppa, repository

I'm trying to install wine on Ubuntu Mate 18.04. Whenever I add the repository I get the error message

> Blockquote E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
>   N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
>   N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

It's given the same error message for a few other programs I've tried to install too. Is it because 18.04 is so new it doesn't officially support it yet?

Comment: The error message means exactly what it says - the ppa does not support 18.04, in fact it does not support 17.10 either and at the ppa's webpage there is a message that says: `!!! PLEASE NOTE THAT THIS REPOSITORY IS DEPRECATED !!!`

Comment: You may want to try to phase out your use of wine, as it's deprecated now.

Answer (score 5):

18.04 has been out for less than a week.  As such, many developers haven't caught up to the new release yet.  To that end, [WineHQ has a bug for this already](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45085) requesting 18.04 packaging in their repository.

There is Wine 3.0 in the Ubuntu repositories, you can use that in the interim by executing `sudo apt install wine`.  Once the upstream WineHQ repositories catch up you can use them.

Once that time is available, you can follow the instructions for installing from their repos.  From [their instructions page](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) are the instructions to follow at that  time:

> *If you have previously installed a Wine package from another repository, please remove it and any packages that depend on it (e.g.,
>   wine-mono, wine-gecko, winetricks) before attempting to install the
>   WineHQ packages, as they may cause dependency conflicts.*
>
> If your system is 64 bit, enable 32 bit architecture (if you haven't
>   already):
>
> ```
> sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
> ```
>
> Add the repository:
>
> ```
> wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
> sudo apt-key add Release.key
> sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
> ```
>
> Update packages:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> ```
>
> Then install ***one*** of the following packages:
>
> Stable Branch:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
> ```
>
> Development Branch:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel
> ```
>
> Staging Branch:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-staging
> ```
>
> If apt-get complains about missing dependencies, install them, then repeat the last two steps (update and install).

Staging isn't really used anymore, so use either Stable or Devel.

**There will be differences though:**

> - Files are installed to `/opt/wine-devel`.
> - Menu items are not created for Wine's builtin programs (`winecfg`, etc.), and if you are upgrading from a distro package that had added
>     them, they will be removed. You can recreate them yourself using your
>     menu editor.
> - Binfmt_misc registration is not added. Consult your distro's documentation for
>     [`update-binfmts`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/update-binfmts.8.html)
>     if you wish to do this manually.
> - WineHQ does not at present package `wine-gecko` or `wine-mono`. When creating a new wine prefix, you will be asked if you want to download
>     those components. For best compatibility, it is recommended to click
>     Yes here. If the download doesn't work for you, please follow the
>     instructions on the [Gecko](http://wiki.winehq.org/Gecko) and
>     [Mono](http://wiki.winehq.org/Mono) wiki pages to install them
>     manually.

Comment: Thanks.  I can't download from those repositories though, because I get the same "no valid release file" error message.

Comment: @Weboh 18.04 right?

Comment: Yep. Is it just so new it's not supported? I'm about ready to install Xenial.

Comment: @Weboh I am also having the same vice as you; The system upgrade has only been out for mere days, the wonderful people over at winehq need a bit of time to update their releases. I expect it should be out in the next week if not sooner.

Comment: @Weboh and all: This is a known issue on WineHQ's bugs/issue tracker - https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45085 - and there hasn't been much move on it yet.  The issue is that Ubuntu 18.04 is less than a week old and in turn is "so new" that upstreams haven't yet adopted it on build platforms.  I would track the Wine Bug until we know it's available.  In the interim, I believe there's Wine 3.0 in the repositories you can use - once the WineHQ repos have 18.04 releases you can switch to that.

Comment: @Weboh 3.0 may be "too old" according to Wine upstream in the AppDB, but you can still use it until they update their repositories...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest just installing wine-stable from the Ubuntu repos.  They have verison 3.0-1ubuntu1 which is pretty up to date.

Remove any wine-related ppas you have installed and give the command

`sudo apt install wine-stable`

Comment: Thanks. I thought I was using the official repo before... 

Anyway, how can I completly remove the old installation? I removed all the packages using Synaptic and deleted the .wine directory in my home folder but mate-menu still shows a wine submenu when it's supposedly not installed. And when I reinstall wine, it doesn't work correctly (and there's no wine-config entry in mate-menu, though the wine submenu with programs installed with the old wine installation is still there...).

Comment: I don't know MATE but on my LXDE-over-Ubuntu installs wine leaves a lot of trash entries in /home/[user]/.local/share/applications  There must be 30 entries in there for Windows Media Player! You could check there and clean out wine related stuff.

Comment: Just an FYI, but if you want the 'latest' stable Wine you should be using their repos (which I touch upon in my answer).  the PPA doesn't anymore and is actually deprecated in favor of WineHQ's repos.

Comment: @ThomasWard thanks, but I was using version 1~something before I upgraded to 18.04. 3.0 is plenty sexy for me. And I avoid ppas where possible.

Comment: Cool cool, I'm just making a note.  Stable Wine is 3.0, but once they release a new 'Stable" release they start calling the older stable releases "no longer supported".

Comment: Actually 3.0 is no longer listed on the AppDB as a supported version, so it's interesting to note that 3.0 might be "too old" now...