# Broken Packages with wine

Tags: package-management, wine, 17.10, dependencies

I know the question has been asked a lot but nothing I can find seems to be working. When I enter:

```
sudo apt-get install wine-stable
```

Here is what I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable : Depends: wine-stable-amd64 (= 3.0.1~trusty) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: wine-stable-i386 (= 3.0.1~trusty)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Working on Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install wine-stable-amd64 wine-stable-i386 wine-stable`

Comment: I get The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable-amd64 : Depends: libgphoto2-port10 (>= 2.5.2) but it is not installable
                     Recommends: libcapi20-3 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libgnutls26 (>= 2.12.17-0) but it is not installable
                     Recommends: libosmesa6 (>= 6.5.2-1) but it is not going to be installed or
                                 libgl1-mesa-glide3 but it is not installable
                     Recommends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not installable
and similar for the other

Comment: Installing recommended to see if that helps

Comment: precise ubuntu version for others people who may have answer

Comment: I have Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Why are you trying to install 14.04 (Trusty) packages in a 17.10 system? Looks like you are trying to add some PPA? What instructions are you following? Please edit your question instead of burying important information in comments.

Comment: @user535733 I may be? What would be the correct thing to do?

Comment: In the absence of more information, uninstall all those PPA packages, disable that PPA source (it's not your friend), and then install wine from the Ubuntu repositories (the easy way).

Comment: @user535733 i tried installing from the ubuntu software center the first time and got the same issue.  But I'll try it out.  Would it be best to do wine or wine (development version) ?

Comment: Don't blame Software Center -- it's just a tool that does your bidding. When you add an unwise source, it's lousy packages show in the Software Center. That's why you must exercise good judgement about what sources to add to your system. The official Ubuntu repositories provide a single version of Wine, so if you are doing it correctly you don't need to choose a version.

Comment: @DillonFowler you should be using the Wine upstream repositories for that version of Ubuntu, if you want a Wine repo.  The Wine PPA has been deprecated for a while in favor of Wine's upstream repositories.

Comment: @ThomasWard thanks. But how would I do that one?

Comment: Wine has a guide for using their repos, I have those steps summarized in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031703/10616), but the [WineHQ instructions page is usually more up-to-date](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu).

Comment: @ThomasWard when going through the steps, everything works until Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-g3w8Cs/11-libsane1_1.0.27-1~experimental2ubuntu2.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: @DillonFowler Not enough info, I would need to see the entire command line output from `apt`, it sounds like you've got something broken somewhere on your environment, though, if that also doesn't work and broken packages start cropping up.  Or something else updated that package and that in turn broke many things.

Comment: @ThomasWard my laptop died and I can't get the full message that was there now.  When I went to redo it, I also did autoremove.  Now it says that winehq-stable is installed.  So I'm not sure if it's fixed or not.

Comment: @ThomasWard when i try to run anything with wine i only get a black screen and cannot close the application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)